# jenkins plugins installed via CLI inside docker container is not showing up in jenkins web console

Tags: jenkins, docker, containers, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

According to the README.md file in the [official JenkinsCI for Docker](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/) repository, I have started a jenkins master in a docker container with a named volume such as this

```
$ docker run -d \
--publish 8080:8080 \
--volume jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
--name jenkins_master \
jenkins
```

After that, I have used the browser to:

- visit `localhost:8080`,
- installed a few plugins from the jenkins web console,
- ran a few pipelines
- etc

All worked fine.

---

Later i tried to install some jenkins plugins via CLI (instead of the web console) like the following

```
$ docker exec -it jenkins_master /bin/bash
$ install-plugins.sh hockeyapp
```

It shows that everything installed correctly. However, when i visit `localhost:8080` via the browser, i see that the `hockeyapp` plugin was not installed.

**How can i make sure that plugins are available from the web console, while I install them from `docker exec` CLI?**

---

Noteworthy, i found that there are 2 different plugins folder. One where `hockeyapp` is available. One where `hockeyapp` is not available.

```
$ ls /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/ # shows hockeyapp
$ ls /var/jenkins_home/plugins/      # does not show hockeyapp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `install-plugins.sh` is designed for **pre**-installing plugins.

Plugins that you install in that way will be picked up **when the container starts**, from the `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/` directory that you mentioned.

Try ***restarting*** (or stopping and then starting) the container again. After that you should see the newly installed plugins appear correctly in the web console.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the `ref` directory part? Where am i supposed to "mention" it?

Comment: do you mean it only requires a restart of the docker container?

Comment: Yes, I think so. With the `ref` container, I was referring to the path `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/` that appears in your question.

Comment: i became very impatient to see results. A simple restart of the docker container was all that was required. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like install-plugins.sh is depreciated now.

use:

```
jenkins-plugin-cli -f PATH_TO_FILE
```